# Increasement number not rising in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am trying to figure this out. I have 3 buttons id (test1, test2, test3) in my HTML! In my jQuery I have an click function in a for loop like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("#test"+i).on('click', function() {
            alert("I am clicked! ("+i+")");
        });
    }  
});
```

Now, I am alerting a message for each of them, nut all the (i) in the alert is giving the last number "3"... How do i get it to write "I am clicked (1)" if I press test1 and equally if I press test2 and test3?

[I have a jsfiddle to explain here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jmansa/vbdKU/)

Hoping for help and thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $("#test"+i).on('click', function() {
       var value = $(this).attr('id');
           value=value.replace("test", "");
           value=parseInt(value)+1;
        alert("I am clicked! ("+value+")");
    });
}  
});
```

Comment: Actually... Both solutions are great although this one works best with my solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the handlers you're assigning have an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, not a *copy* of that variable as of when the function was created. They're *closures* over the `i` variable (and other things). More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

There are several ways to solve this.

1. You can put a piece of information on the elements so they can all share a *single* handler, which is probably preferred. (You actually already have that information in your example, we can figure out `i` from the elements' `id` values, but I'm assuming in the real world things are more complex.)

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           $("#test"+i).attr("data-index", i).click(clickHandler);
       }  

       function clickHandler() {
           alert("I am clicked! ("+this.getAttribute("data-index")+")");
           // Or:
           alert("I am clicked! ("+$(this).attr("data-index")+")");
       }
   });
   ```

   [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbdKU/1/)

   Note how we have just **one** handler function, and it handles clicks on all of the elements.

   Using a single handler may also mean you can take advantage of *event delegation*, hooking the `click` on an ancestor element rather than on each of these individual elements, e.g.:

   ```
   $("selector for ancestor").on("click", "[id^=test]", ...);
   ```

   [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbdKU/2/)
2. You can use a builder function to create the click handlers so that they close over something that doesn't change (an argument we pass to the builder):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           $("#test"+i).on('click', buildHandler(i));
       }  

       function buildHandler(index) {
           return function() {
               alert("I am clicked! ("+index+")");
           };
       }
   });
   ```

   [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbdKU/3/)